# A more elegant solution to avoid disposing the DbContext while having background tasks still running

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

The code below works as intended but I am not sure is the most elegant I would use.

```
 using (DatabaseContext context = DatabaseContext.CreateContext(_incompleteConnString + prefix + campaignDBPlatform))
     Progress prog = new Progress();
     TaskFactory tf = new TaskFactory();
     var parent = tf.StartNew(() =>
      Parallel.ForEach(QuestionsLangConstants.questionLangs.Values, i =>
      {
        try
        {
         qrepo.UploadQuestions(QWorkBook.Worksheets[i.QSheet], i, prog);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
       })
    );
    prog.Show();
    var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(i =>
    {
    using (DatabaseContext context2 = DatabaseContext.CreateContext(_incompleteConnString + prefix + campaignDBPlatform))
    {
      UploadedQuestionsRepliesRepository uqrepo = new    
      UploadedQuestionsRepliesRepository(context2);
      UploadedQuestionsReplies UQuestions = new UploadedQuestionsReplies() {
        Id = (int)uqrepo.getNextSeqValue(),
        FileName = "test", 
        RQType = Questions.QuestionsType.ToString(), 
        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now 
        };
     uqrepo.Insert(UQuestions);
     uqrepo.Save();
    }
  });
}
```

If I do not add `context2` `context` gets disposed while I am when parent continues. If I use a `finalTask.Wait()` however the UI freezes. Is there a better solution to what I have above?

Comment: You really need to format the code properly...

Comment: You have two `context2` variables an no `context` variable.

Comment: You will not gain any advantage by using Parallel ForEach inside of a task and moreover you will just introduce more problems than without it.

Comment: @phillip Why don't I gain anything by making the foreach parallel. The workbook has many sheets that I need to parse and I want to do in parallel. The Task is there to make this parsing in a background thread so as that the UI thread remains responsive (i.e. the Progress form gets updated). Is there a better way to do that? I could start each method call in a new thread but I thought this way I could do it more cleanly.

Comment: @idipous this is bigger than a comment box but I will include a link for you.  When to use plinq and when not... http://blog.mssoftwareconsulting.com/msswc/blog/file.axd?file=WhenToUseParallelForEachOrPLINQ.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could avoid the first using. Use the context in both cases and if you are sure that the second task will always be executed, dispose it at the end, otherwise add some extra code to make sure that your context is always disposed.

```
DatabaseContext context2 = DatabaseContext.CreateContext(_incompleteConnString + prefix + campaignDBPlatform)
//Initialize qrepo with the context here??
Progress prog = new Progress();
TaskFactory tf = new TaskFactory();
var parent = tf.StartNew(() =>
  Parallel.ForEach(QuestionsLangConstants.questionLangs.Values, i =>
  {
    try
    {
     qrepo.UploadQuestions(QWorkBook.Worksheets[i.QSheet], i, prog);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     // Do you really want to continue with the next task after the exception?
    }
   })
);
prog.Show();
var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(i =>
{
  UploadedQuestionsRepliesRepository uqrepo = new UploadedQuestionsRepliesRepository(context2);
  UploadedQuestionsReplies UQuestions = new UploadedQuestionsReplies() {
        Id = (int)uqrepo.getNextSeqValue(), 
        FileName = "test", 
        RQType = Questions.QuestionsType.ToString(), 
        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now 
    };
    uqrepo.Insert(UQuestions);
    uqrepo.Save();
    context2.Dispose();
 });

}
```

Comment: Good catch about the exception and the next task.